# Running psql command from Python to restore from a PostgreSQL dump file

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

How would I run this psql command from a Python script?

```
psql dbname < dump.sql
```

I have looked at subprocess, but it is not clear how to handle the `<` redirect from file.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/Jaymon/dump, if you don't want to worry about writing your own tool.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you first created the db, in Python

```
import os
...
os.system("psql -U postgres  -d {0} -f  {1}".format(my_database,my_sql_restorefile) )
```